# combine and sum multiple groups

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, report

I have been having trouble for a while figuring this out.I have managed to generate fields based on weeks.

[image]

Now I want something like this

[image]

In Crystal reports How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried `insert summary` option

Comment: Yes, I have tried it but it returns the same result!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have faced the same case and i found 2 options to solve the same
1- from db level you can add new column to get week number in that year and then get the sum value according to week number.

2- from crystal report, you can set number of weeks in a running field and use mod to get the division remaining (week number mod 2), if it is equal to zero then you can get the sum or reset the sum parameter.

[image]

in the formula sum field:

```
{@DayName} = "Friday" AND {RptEmpMove;1.WeekNum} mod 2 = 0
```

Comment: Hi can you give me an example how to do this thanks!

Comment: @UnknownX i have updated my answer and added the examples

Comment: @abdulrahman-88  I have managed get weekly summary using SQL  Thanks a lot